# Redirect with Slim Framework

Tags: php, url-rewriting, php-5.3, slim

I have the following code:

```
$app->get('/category/:name', function($name){
  //the render files are found under the templates folder
header('Location: searchPage.php?crs_category=$name');
});
```

The problem is that when I type `/category/business` its just lands on blank page. I do not want to render the page because I can't exactly render searchPage.php?crs_category because it is view as a template and there's a work around to include to variable. I just want to go directly to that page while keeping the url clean. Essentially redirect to this page in the background with the url remaining that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache as a webserver, couldn't you just rewrite the URL in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

..or if you want a real redirect

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

PS If you insist on doing it in Slim, you could try

```
$app->get('/category/:name', function($name) use ($app) {
    $app->response->redirect('/searchPage.php?crs_category='.$name, 303);
});
```

source: http://docs.slimframework.com/response/helpers/#redirect

Comment: thanks for the response. I avoid using htaccess because i often run into issues with it. Either it doesnt work properly in localhost or/and it doesnt work in host For the Slim response, i tried your suggested, and got the following error Message: Undefined variable: app

Comment: Pardon my typo, I've edited the snippet, it should have `use ($app)` to import the `$app` variable into function scope (assuming you've instantiated your Slim App to that variable  (`$app = new \Slim\Slim();`)

Comment: thank you one last inquiry how would i be able to keep the url masked to the clean one?

Comment: and also ensure that when someone type searchPage.php?crs_category that get masked to category/business thanks

Comment: I think that you should distinct URL _redirection_ from URL _rewriting_ (there's a great [article](https://moz.com/blog/url-rewrites-and-301-redirects-how-does-it-all-work) about that). _Redirection_ could be done in Slim, but for URL _rewriting_ I think you'll have to resort to `.htaccess`

Comment: thank you. I realize htaccess is the proper approach for this task but i rely on slim for so many other things and realize that i cant use slim + rewrite rule in htaccess since slim redirect all request to index